# Elasticsearch. Is it possible to make Elastisearch use only numbers in auto assigned IDs?

Tags: elasticsearch

When Elasticsearch index document and you do not provide ID, it assign auto ID which consists of 20 symbols (letters and numbers). I need to use numbers only. Is it possible to change mask/pattern/type of auto assigned ID?

Comment: This is currently not supported by ES, you can provide your own numerical ID sequence, though they will always be transformed to string first when used as the `_id`

Comment: Could you write your answer as Answer, not comment? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported by ES, you can provide your own numerical ID sequence, though they will always be transformed to string first when used as the `_id`